# After wordpress update , its giving jquery version error

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I just updated my WordPress website from version 5 to 6 and In the console it shows this error:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

due to this issue, all the images are disappeared.

I checked the jQuery file and it says the current version is 1.12

[image]

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. Even jQuery 1.12 is horribly outdated, being nearly eight years old

Comment: It is a very clear message. Update your jQuery to the requested version

Comment: First turn off your cache and test. 2nd check the order of your scrips. Boostrap js need to be loaded after jquery. Also what is the bootstrap version ? Is your theme updated for 6+ wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been given on a WordPress forum [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-version-1-9-1-or-higher-2/)

it could be due to WordPress's jQuery or any JQmigrate used within plugins.

Use the following code in your functions.php

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js', false, null);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Replace the jQuery URL with any active URL you want to use. Let me know if it works for you.